# Implementing a FCFS scheduler

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

I am trying to simulate a FCFS scheduler and the way I am doing it is by when a thread comes in it if it isn't in the queue I push it on the queue, but if it is then check to see if the thread is at the head of the queue (first in) and the time remaining for the job is > 0.  My problem is how do I put a thread in a wait state until it is the head of the queue?  I hear conditional variables might help but not sure how they work.

```
if (!(is_in_queue(ready_queue, tid))) { //thread is not in the queue
            pthread_mutex_lock(&schedule_lock);
            ready_queue = enqueue(ready_queue, currentTime, tid, remainingTime, tprio);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&schedule_lock);
        }
        else{ //thread is in queue
            if (tid == head_of_queue(ready_queue) && remainingTime >0) { //need to schedule this thread for full time 
                return currentTime +1; //schedule on the next unit of "time"
            }
            else if (tid == head_of_queue(ready_queue) && remainingTime == 0){ //need to go to next task
                pthread_mutex_lock(&schedule_lock);
                ready_queue = dequeue(ready_queue);
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&schedule_lock);
            }
            else{ //not at the head of the queue
               //How do i wait until it is at the head??
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A condition variable allows the OS to suspend the execution of a thread until another thread sends a signal to wake it up.  For your else statement you need something like

```
pthread_cond_wait(&cond_var, &mutex_var);
```

That will put a thread to sleep.  However, you will also need to think about when to wake up the thread.  Probably if a thread is not at the head of the queue then you should use `pthread_cond_broadcast` to wake up all waiting threads.  You will also want to have a loop so that each thread checks the condition each time that it is woken up.  So your initial `if` statement should probably be something like a `while` loop.